# Maven central repo: Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:backend read error

Tags: java, maven

In the continuous integration system (travis-ci.org) on our project, I'm starting to get error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.6-SNAPSHOT:start (start-container) on project p6spy-it: Failed resolving artifact: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-distribution:zip:6.1.0.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-distribution/6.1.0.Final/jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:backend read error.
[ERROR] org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-distribution:zip:6.1.0.Final
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] cloudbees-release (http://repository-p6spy.forge.cloudbees.com/release, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] sonatype-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] sonatype-apache (https://repository.apache.org/releases/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache-snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

Full build output can be seen on: https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/15104889/log.txt?deansi=true

If I access the problematic url via browser: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-distribution/6.1.0.Final/jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip
I get the same error as well:

```
Error 503 backend read error
```

However one day back all was fine.

What should I do with that/How to fix that? Just wait for them to refresh some internal caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If downloading remote artifacts is mission critical for your build, have you considered running your own instance of Nexus?

- http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

This will protect you against transient networking and server errors, by acting as a local cache inside your network. It'll also improve the performance of your build processes.

A second lessor option is to use the alternate URLs provided by the Search service:

- [jboss page on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.jbossas%7Cjboss-as-distribution%7C6.1.0.Final%7Cpom)
- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-distribution/6.1.0.Final/jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip

Maybe, just maybe you'll get redirected to a webserver that is either hosted on S3 or in a more available cluster.

Finally if you're interested in what Sonatype are doing to scale up Maven Central, their blogs have postd some interesting updates:

- http://blog.sonatype.com/people/tag/central/
- http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2012/07/we-just-kicked-central-performance-and-availability-up-a-notch-with-edgecast/
- http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2008/12/central-maven-repository-taffic-using-s3/

Comment: well, my problem is that the build runs on travis-ci.org => hosted maven repo is not an option, since we're using free stuff only (comming with github - our project: https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy-it). And the url from maven search? well in the meantime, I just went for http downloads anyway, I might update links to search service urls as these are more bound to maven. Anyway, as we run with cargo, I've created bug report: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-1241 Still you answered what I asked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

(1) Download **jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.pom** and **jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip** from the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.jbossas%7Cjboss-as-distribution%7C6.1.0.Final%7Cpom).

(2) Install the zip file into your local Maven repository manually.

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip \
    -DpomFile=jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.pom
```

It seems *"Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:backend read error."* error occurs when the target zip file is big. I encountered the same error when downloading appengine-java-sdk-1.9.0.zip.